# Returning class type in ruby

Tags: ruby, class

I need a function that checks the namespace of the argument, and returns the class type

for example:

```
checkType(id)
   if id starts with "p:"
   return <Class Type>
end
```

I do not have an instance to use when checking the type of the id

Comment: I have a hard time understanding this question. You want to return the class of an object, but you don't actually have the object but just an id for the object? If so, what kind of id is it? It can't be the object_id because that's a number and couldn't possibly start with "p:".

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of a lame, hackish approach, but if you know what the IDs are that you're looking for, and there's not too many, you could create a hash mapping of ID to ClassType.